# variable changes for unknown reason(maybe)

Tags: php

i have this function

```
    function ecr_form_save($data) {
/* data value
array(
['result'] =>
'ok'
)
*/
        $result = validate_form($data);
        global $firephp;    
        $firephp->log($result, 'Iterators');
        //return $result;   //return 1

        if ($result['result']=="ok") {
            return $result; //return 2
        } else {
            return $result; //return 3
        }

    }
```

When i uncoment return 1 everything works, but if i comment return 1 and try to get output from return 2 or 3 i get error

Any idea what is going on with that.

yes ,it is always is returning array like this array('result'=>'ok') or like this array('error'=>'"Beigu rādījums" ir jābūt veselam skaitlim') , depending on what input form has.

if i change if statement to if ( 1==1) it works  to

Comment: Are you quite sure that there actually is a key `result` inside of `$result`. Consider adding `is_array($result)` and `isset($result['result'])` to your `if`.

Comment: i'd check whether $result is an array or not before attempting to access it; also i'd check your validate_form function to make sure it always returns something

Comment: yes ,it is always is returning array like this array('result'=>'ok') or like this array('error'=>'"Beigu rādījums" ir jābūt veselam skaitlim') , depending on what input form has.

Comment: try putting in print_r() lines for $data and $result

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you `var_dump($result)` after 'return 1' - it might not be a true array.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your if statement to:

> if( is_array($result) && isset($result['result']) &&
>   $result['result']=="ok" ){

Comment: if i change my if to this it works, anyone can explain me what is going on?

Comment: The if statement is making sure that the result variable is an array and that it includes the 'result' key BEFORE checking the value of this key.

Comment: i understood that, but why it fails without checking, if the incoming variable is always the same

Comment: Are you sure the variable stays the same? Have you done a print_r($result) just before the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

u have to do

```
array("result" =>"ok");
```

now try it's work.